# How to restrict underscore from occuring in middle of a strings of digit

Tags: regex

I want the "_" characters to occur only in the middle of a string, not at the beginning or at the end. How can I place that restriction?

Ex :

```
_8484          (invalid) 
8484_          (invalid)
88_            (invalid)

8              (valid)
8______8       (valid)
8231_8484_545  (valid) - Want regex for this
```

Comment: My try : /^([0-9]+_[0-9]+)+$/

Comment: Thanks for the response.This string "7___7_1" not matched.May be I should have mentioned it can have many underscore in between the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9_]*[0-9])$
```

This says:

- ^ start of string/line
- [0-9] any numeric character
- or
- [0-9] any numeric character
- [_0-9]* zero or more of any numeric or underscore characters
- [0-9] any numeric character
- $ end of line/string

In other words: match any string that is a single numeric charactor, or, any string that begins with a numeric character, followed by zero or more of any numeric character or underscore, ending with any numeric character.

Comment: Thanks for the response.It is working fine but can you make it by using \d or [0-9] ? The reason is I dont want to match alphabets

Comment: @mike I'm sure you could envisage replacing `.*` with `[0-9_]+`.

Comment: @mike you should edit your original question so that it is consistent with what you really want.

Comment: @mangotang thanks a lot. But what If I want to match just exactly one digit not followed by anything.